Azure Data Factory send data from sql using email in table format
I have issue with web activity using ADF to send email in table format,

i have table in sql and i can retrive it using lookup activty and data can shown in adf
this is output from lookup

and this is result from email, not showing the data just only showing the expression of ADF web JSON

this is the Expression web activity
{
  "ITEmailTO": "@{variables('emailsummary')}",
  "dataFactoryName": "@{pipeline().DataFactory}",
  "pipelineName": "@{pipeline().Pipeline}",
  "subject": "Summary Error Report from Table",
  "ErrorMessage": "@concat(
    '<html><body><h3>Contact Info</h3><table border=\"1\">',
    '<tr><th>FileName</th><th>Target</th><th>ErrorDetails</th></tr>',
    join(
        activities('Lookup').output.value,
        '<tr><td>',
        item().FileName,
        '</td><td>',
        item().Target,
        '</td><td>',
        item().ErrorDetails,
        '</td></tr>'
    ),
    '</table></body></html>'
  )"
}

any idea, how to show the data in format table just only using ADF.
Maybe this is the expected table that shown in email


Are you using logic app to send the mail?

@RakeshGovindula just added the expected result in email

yes im using logic app azure to send the mail

Did you tried to format this in the logic app after getting JSON from lookup?

not yet, any insight? how to doit?


not yet, any insight? how to doit?

If you want to send all lookup data to mail as table, you can try formatting it using Create table HTML in the logic app.
First pass the lookup activity output array from web activity body to the logic app like below.
{
"ITEmailTO": "mymail",
"dataFactoryName": "@{pipeline().DataFactory}",
"pipelineName": "@{pipeline().Pipeline}",
"subject": "Summary Error Report from Table",
"ErrorMessage":@{activity('Lookup1').output.value}
}

Now, in the logic app, after HTTP request received step, add create HTML table step and pass the lookup activity output array from the previous step's body. Open the expression and give the expression triggerBody()?['ErrorMessage'] and click on ok.

Now, pass the output of this step as the body of the outlook action from the Dynamic content.

You can pass your mail id and Subject from the HTTP step using expression like triggerBody()?['ITEmailTO'] and triggerBody()?['subject'].
Table in mail:

If you want to send mail for every row, you need to trigger logic app in a loop from ADF or create loop in logic app and use these steps in that loop. You need to change the expression as per the loop.

if i have 100 rows ,do i need to create loop 100x times?

If you want to send mail for every row, then you need to loop through that lookup array 100 times. You can make use of for loop in the logic app. Or if you want to send the total lookup output array as table in a single mail, then there is no need of loop.

why its still error= The 'from' property value in the 'table' action inputs is of type 'String'. The value must be of type 'Array'.

Did you tried to pass like this in the web activity body "ErrorMessage":@{activity('Lookup1').output.value}? can you provide your expression? and where are you getting error? in ADF or logic app?

i got error when logic apps running, in ADF no error .

Did you tried to pass like this in the web activity body "ErrorMessage":@{activity('Lookup1').output.value} ? I mean the whole lookup activity output array sent to through the body right? and can you show your error step expression in the logic app?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
